# PHP Application & Wireless Barcode Scanner

Tags: php, sql, barcode

We have finished up on a stock management system, and the client has asked for a feature in which when deliveries come into the warehouse, he can scan each container with a wireless barcode scanner. The barcode on the container will contain the information of each product within that container (Eg. 100meter roll, color:red etc..).

My question is, what would the best way of doing this be?. Either way, in order for the stock to be updated as the deliveries come in, the user will have to plugin the scanner in, and offload the data?.

Has anyone had experience with this?

I'm trying to find the most simple way of doing this. I have a good idea for the php application itself, just trying to work out how these scanners work wirelessly.

Comment: I know the wired ones act as a keyboard input device, it should just input the numbers when you scan it. Like typing really quick. :) Pretty sure the wireless ones should work the same, as long as you hook them upto a PC and not some networked ones.

Comment: Yeah, we have created an application that does this. However, we are after a solution where the computer is not near the device, and therefore needs to be stored on the barcode reader itself.

Comment: I think you are going to have to write a native application that reads the information off of the barcode reader and uses an http client component to send the updated information to your php service.